# Queue function call in javascript

Tags: javascript, queue

I have functions that contain timed animation and i want these functions to run one after the other just when the previous one is done.

```
function a() {
    var i = 0;
    var x = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('a' + i);
        if (i == 3) {
            console.log('Done @' + i);
            clearInterval(x);
            return true;
        }
        i++;
    }, 1000);
}

function b() {
    var c = 0;
    var y = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('b' + c);
        if (c == 1) {
            console.log('Done 2 @' + c);
            clearInterval(y);
            return true;
        }
        c++;
    }, 1000);
}

a().then(b());
```

I tried one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302301/forcing-one-javascript-function-to-wait-to-run-until-the-first-has-finished) but it's not working. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lungx/1/).

What i want to achieve is like this:

`a0`

`a1`

`a2`

`a3`

`Done @3`

`b0`

`b1`

`Done 2 @1`

but it stops at `Done @3`. Im looking for any other ways to achieve this.

Comment: `a()` needs to return an object with a `then` method (a promise) for your code to work. Your implementation returns nothing, so `then` does nothing and `b()` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call `then` method – function must return promise, after then you don’t want to immediate call `b()` but pass reference to it **`a().then(b);`**

```
function a() {
    var i = 0;
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var x = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('a' + i);
        if (i == 3) {
            console.log('Done @' + i);
            clearInterval(x);
            defer.resolve('asdasd');
        }
        i++;
    }, 1000);
    return defer;
}

function b() {
    var c = 0;
    var y = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('b' + c);
        if (c == 1) {
            console.log('Done 2 @' + c);
            clearInterval(y);
            return true;
        }
        c++;
    }, 1000);
}
a().then(b);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lungx/3/

Answer (score 1):

Two simpler approaches that should generally work, though maybe not in your case.

(1) jQuery.  If you're using the jQuery `animate()` function, then you can set each animation in the callback for the animation previous.  That way when animation `n` finishes, your callback function will start the animation for `n+1`, etc.  There is a discussion and a couple examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

(2) If you're animating (or transitioning, really) CSS, you can attach a handler to the `transitionend` event.  That way, similar to the first approach, you can have the next transition begin as soon as the previous `transitionend` event fires.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), especially under the header "Detecting the completion of a transition."

I've used the first approach before, and I don't see any reason why the second shouldn't work.  I hope this helps. Let me know if it doesn't work; I'm curious.